# Convert XML date/time to Oracle Date/Time format

Tags: c#, xml, oracle

I have a date/time value in xml document that looks like this:

> 2012-02-29T00:00:00+01:00

I have to convert that date to oracle date in this format

> dd.MM.yyyy hh24:mi:ss

I tried like this:

```
string cre_date = "convert(to_date,'" + dr_art_apa["CreationDateTime"] + 
"', 'dd.MM.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')";
```

But nothing, so help somebody!!!

Comment: I also tried this cre_date = string.Format("to_timestamp('{0:dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss}','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')", dr_art_apa["CreationDateTime"]); But i got error ORA-01850: hour must be between 0 and 23

Comment: what do you mean - nothing? what does cre_date contain after run? What do you want it to contain?

Comment: cre_date is a string variable that I pass to ora procedure, so it has to contain a date value in format dd.mm.yyyy hh:mi:ss

Comment: Can you show us the code how you call the Stored Procedure ? and what is the type in the stored procedure that gets the string of cre_date ?

Comment: com1.CommandText = "TRB01.set_idoc('DOC','1','"
                                                   + sender + "','"
                                                   + reciver + "',"
                                                   + cre_date + ",'"
                                                   + bod_ID + "')";
                com1.ExecuteNonQuery();

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try it like this:

```
com1.CommandText = "TRB01.set_idoc('DOC','1','" + sender + "','" + reciver + "'," +
                    "to_timestamp_tz('"+ cre_date + "','yyyy-mm-dd\"T\"hh24:mi:ss:TZH:TZM'),'" + 
                     bod_ID + "')"; 
com1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Though a better solution should be by havaing a `DateTime` in c# code and adding it as an OracleParameter

Answer (score 0):

var dt = DateTime.Parse("2012-02-29T00:00:00+01:00").ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");

Comment: in var dt I have to pass this: dr_art_apa["CreationDateTime"] a value from data reader

Comment: so u tried the same code like Paul mentioned, but like that?: `var dt = DateTime.Parse("2012-02-29T00:00:00+01:00").ToString(dr_art_apa["CreationDateTime"]);`

Comment: I don't get this eMI... This date "2012-02-29T00:00:00+01:00" it not alwasy the same, i have date value in data reader that I have to extract, and that value is alway different

Comment: yes that was just an example, in your case, use:`var dt = DateTime.Parse(dr_art_apa["CreationDateTime"]).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");`

Comment: That is not working, i got error: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'